# Setting Managed Propety Refinable Option with PS

Tags: 2013, powershell, managed-property

I'm trying to configure managed properties through PowerShell but there's one particular parameter that I can't figure out. I want to make a certain property refinable but none of the commands [listed on TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608001.aspx) seem to correspond to that. I tried just using a `-Refinable $true` param but PS is telling me that doesn't exist.

**Edit:** I can see the property itself with `$Property | Get-Member Refinable` but can't for the life of me figure out how to change it! My C# logic of trying `$Property.Properties["Refinable"] = $true` doesn't seem to work because the `.Properties` method is returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my variable name. You can't call something "$Property" if it actually has a properties bag! Renamed it to "$Managed" and it worked just fine. Silly PowerShell.

For reference, once I changed the variable name I was able to set the property like this (this exact method did *not* work while using the old variable name):

```
$Managed.Refinable = $true
$Managed.Update()
```

Comment: Do you have to run a full crawl afterwards for this to take effect, or does it become refinable immediately (assuming the prop in question has already been added to the index)?